# reject button always updates the first record issue

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I made a view with records and each one has accepted and rejected button. On reject, there is a pop-up a modal for writing why. the issue here is whenever I click reject button for any record, it takes the id and status of the first record and the `type="button"`. I tried changing the type of the reject button `type="submit"`, it works but it goes directly to the controller without showing the popup. literally, I'm going crazy .what am I doing wrong?

```
  <tbody>
                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model._Requests.Count(); i++)
                            {


                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x=>Model._Requests[i].Request_ID , new {Name="theId" })
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model._Requests[i].Account_Name)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model._Requests[i].LOB)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model._Requests[i].Operation_Date)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model._Requests[i].Employee_no)
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model._Requests[i].Fulfillment_Rate)
                                    </td>

                                    @if (Model._Requests[i].Status == false)
                                    {
                                        <td>
                                            <span name="badge" class="badge badge-warning" id="pend">pending training</span>

                                        </td>
                                    }
                                    @if (Model._Requests[i].Status == true)
                                    {
                                        <td>
                                            <span name="badge" class="badge badge-pill badge-success">completed</span>

                                        </td>
                                    }
                                    @if (Model._Requests[i].Status == null)
                                    {
                                        <td>
                                            <span name="badge" class="badge badge-warning" id="pend">pending</span>

                                        </td>
                                    }


                                    <!--for the accept button-->

                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Fulfillment_Accept", "TBL_Request", FormMethod.Post))
                                    {
                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                                        <td>
                                            <button id="btnAccept" class="btn  btn-success" name="a_button" type="submit" value="true">Accept</button>
                                            @Html.Hidden("Request_ID", Model._Requests[i].Request_ID)
                                            @Html.Hidden("Status", Model._Requests[i].Status, new { id = "myEdit", value = "" })

                                        </td>
                                    }
                                    <!--for the reject button-->

                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Fulfillment_Reject", "TBL_Request", FormMethod.Post))
                                    {
                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


                                        <td>

                                            <button id="btnReject" class="btn  btn-danger" name="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" type="button" value="false">Reject</button>
                                            @Html.Hidden("Request_ID", Model._Requests[i].Request_ID)
                                            @Html.Hidden("Status", Model._Requests[i].Status, new { id = "myEdit", value = "" })
                                        </td>
                                        <!--this is the note modal of the reject button -->
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">


                                                        <div class="form-group">


                                                            @Html.TextArea("Note", Model._Requests[i].Note, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="finalSave" />

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                </tr>
                            }
                                </tbody>
<script>

        $(function () {
            var msg = "@(TempData["success"] as string)";
            if (msg !== "") {
                toastr.success('the request status has been updated successfully!');
            }
        });

        $('[name = "a_button"]').click(function () {
            $('[name = "Status"]').val($('[name = "a_button"]').val());

        })

        $('[name = "button"]').click(function () {
            $('[name = "Status"]').val($('[name = "button"]').val());

        })
</script>
```

the controller methods

```
 //accept method for the accept button
        #region fulfillment
        [CustomAuthorize(Roles = AccessRoleHelper.Training_Action)]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add_Fulfillment_Accept(int Request_ID, bool Status)
        {
            var user = db.TBL_Request.Find(Request_ID);

            user.IsApproved = Status  ;
            //db.TBL_Request.Add(user);

            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["success"] = "Done";
            return RedirectToAction("Training_Action");
        }

        //reject method for the reject button
        [CustomAuthorize(Roles = AccessRoleHelper.Training_Action)]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add_Fulfillment_Reject(int theId , bool Status , string Note)
        {
            var selectedRequest = db.TBL_Request.Find(theId);
            selectedRequest.Note = Note;
            selectedRequest.IsApproved = Status;
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["success"] = "Done";
            return RedirectToAction("Training_Action");
        }
        #endregion
```

I really appreciate your help

Comment: Type submit, submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.

Type button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occurs.

Comment: But how to specify when using the type="button" to take the Id of the record i'm editing . not just the first one. I'm using `@Html.Hidden("Request_ID", Model._Requests[i].Request_ID)` to send it with each record with the reject button .but it doesn't work with the reject button

Answer (score 0):

there are some big DONT in your code

1 st you are looping html content so if you give them id make sure they are dynamic as well let me give you an example

say you are creating reject button and your html gonna be

and when you loop it you are gonna get multiple buttons with same id

here in your case the best idea would be calling a client side method here on btn click 
like

input type =button onClieck YourMethodWhichWillShowTheModalAndSubmit()

next thing if input type is submit then it will submit the form and hence the modal will not ever be shown